# jQuery sum of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my HTML

I want a script like this 
in one Textbox I want to add all the amount total and display it 
and in one more textbox I want it like this

```
"name": [{
  "id": 3,
  "qty": 2
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "qty": 5
}]
```

My Updated Question

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="id">
  <input type="text" name="qty">
  <input type="text" name="amount">
</div>
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="id">
  <input type="text" name="qty">
  <input type="text" name="amount">
</div>
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="id">
  <input type="text" name="qty">
  <input type="text" name="amount">
</div>
<button>Click Me!!!</button>
```

My Updated code not working in this js core js is working fine

Comment: What do you mean by "I want a script like this in one Textbox"?

Comment: onchange qty textbox  i want to add like i gave

Comment: How do you calculate `qty` and `id` in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way:

```js
$('input[name="qty"]').change(function(){
  var name = [];
  $('.main').each(function(index,item){
    var obj={};
    obj.id = $(item).find('input[name="id"]').val();
    obj.qty = $(item).find('input[name="qty"]').val();
    name.push(obj)
  });
  console.log(name);
});
```

```css
input{
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="text" name="qty">
    <input type="text" name="amount">
</div>
<div class="main">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="text" name="qty">
    <input type="text" name="amount">
</div>
<div class="main">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="text" name="qty">
    <input type="text" name="amount">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = { 'name' : [] };
var total =  0; 
$(".main").each(function(){
     s['name'].push({ 'id': $(this).find("input[name='id'"]).val(),'qty': $(this).find("input[name='qty'"]).val()});

     total = total + parseFloat($(this).find("input[name='total'"]).val());

});
```

//total gives final sum
//object s gives the array of objects.